# Load maven dependecy source with classifier

Tags: java, maven

I have maven dependecy with **classifier** in my project

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

I try to load sources for this dependecy with command

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

I get an answer

```
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:sources:2.4:compile
```

For other dependencies (without a classifier), the sources load normally.
In the repository https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/
is present json-lib-2.4-jdk15-sources.jar, but missing json-lib-2.4-sources.jar

How load maven dependecy source with classifier?

P.S. If remove the classifier from the description, the dependency is also loaded, but the source code is also not.

Comment: As a dependency you don't define the sources package. The sources packages are intended for IDE's to download in case you want to take a look into the code...Why would you like to have a dependency on a sources package? Will not work?

Comment: I want to debug source code in IDE

Comment: Yeah I expected that...Then you have to configure your appropriate IDE to automatically download the needed source packages. This is not part of the build..